# SQL duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

My problem is the following! I´m trying to extract the records from a database in order to generate a file with them. I attach the query that I am currently doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT '' || '|' ||

        TIME_STAMP || '|' ||

        CLIENT_APP || '|' ||

        INSTANCE_ID || '|' ||

        SERVICE_NAME || '|' ||

        DATE_HOUR_EXECUTION || '|' ||

        STATE_COD || '|' ||

        ERROR_DESC || '|' ||

        LOG_ID || '|' ||

        ''

FROM TABLE_VC.ACCESS_LOG

WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIME_STAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

The problem I have is that I want to retrieve all the records with all the columns, and in case the LOG_ID column has duplicate records, just grab one of those duplicate records. But with the current query it is not working for me.

Original records:

```
values ('2020-04-12 18:46:48','WEB','bck83kuf5ddpgc2thr4anf3d6jpvgm2sk5e4pcke8jncijmm3s052tv07imnr92cj5obqm4dejagkjh8','service','SERVICE','2020-04-12 18:46:48','0','REQUEST-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');

values ('2020-04-12 18:46:48','WEB','bck83kuf5ddpgc2thr4anf3d6jpvgm2sk5e4pcke8jncijmm3s052tv07imnr92cj5obqm4dejagkjh8','service','SERVICE','2020-04-12 18:46:48','0','REQUEST-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb');

values ('2020-04-12 18:46:48','WEB','bck83kuf5ddpgc2thr4anf3d6jpvgm2sk5e4pcke8jncijmm3s052tv07imnr92cj5obqm4dejagkjh8','service','SERVICE','2020-04-12 18:46:48','0','REQUEST-ccccccccccccccccccccccc');

values ('2020-04-12 18:46:48','WEB','bck83kuf5ddpgc2thr4anf3d6jpvgm2sk5e4pcke8jncijmm3s052tv07imnr92cj5obqm4dejagkjh8','service','SERVICE','2020-04-12 18:46:48','0','REQUEST-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');

values ('2020-04-12 18:46:48','WEB','bck83kuf5ddpgc2thr4anf3d6jpvgm2sk5e4pcke8jncijmm3s052tv07imnr92cj5obqm4dejagkjh8','service','SERVICE','2020-04-12 18:46:48','0','REQUEST-ddddddddddddddddddddddd');
```

Desired records:

```
values ('2020-04-12 18:46:48','WEB','bck83kuf5ddpgc2thr4anf3d6jpvgm2sk5e4pcke8jncijmm3s052tv07imnr92cj5obqm4dejagkjh8','service','SERVICE','2020-04-12 18:46:48','0','REQUEST-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');

values ('2020-04-12 18:46:48','WEB','bck83kuf5ddpgc2thr4anf3d6jpvgm2sk5e4pcke8jncijmm3s052tv07imnr92cj5obqm4dejagkjh8','service','SERVICE','2020-04-12 18:46:48','0','REQUEST-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb');

values ('2020-04-12 18:46:48','WEB','bck83kuf5ddpgc2thr4anf3d6jpvgm2sk5e4pcke8jncijmm3s052tv07imnr92cj5obqm4dejagkjh8','service','SERVICE','2020-04-12 18:46:48','0','REQUEST-ccccccccccccccccccccccc');

values ('2020-04-12 18:46:48','WEB','bck83kuf5ddpgc2thr4anf3d6jpvgm2sk5e4pcke8jncijmm3s052tv07imnr92cj5obqm4dejagkjh8','service','SERVICE','2020-04-12 18:46:48','0','REQUEST-ddddddddddddddddddddddd');
```

Delete one of the duplicate registers with LOD_ID 'REQUEST-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'.

Regards!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so your question makes sense to someone who doesn't know anything about your data.

Comment: You can distinct by Unique columns and after that query using IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER function.  The following query should help you:

```sql
SELECT sub.time_stamp, sub.client_app, sub.instance_id, 
       sub.service_name, sub.date_hour_execution, 
       sub.state_cod, sub.error_desc, sub.log_id
FROM (SELECT al.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY al.log_id ORDER BY al.time_stamp) AS ROW_N
      FROM access_log al
      WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE-al.time_stamp) = 2) sub
WHERE sub.row_n = 1;
```

I created this DBFiddle for you to play with. ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f46a0e804506e27763bdaf07d911d35d))

The query use ROW_NUMBER to rank the rows for each LOG_ID based upon the TIME_STAMP.  Then the outer query limits the results to only the most highly ranked row.